# PHP HTML5 to PDF converter needed

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I know this isn't exactly a question that treads new ground, but after a few days of searching around and not being able to find something that satisfies my needs I've decided to ask the community at large for advice.

I am currently running **PHP5** on an **Apache2.2** server. I have to be able to have satisfactory results on both a **Linux** and **Windows XP** machine (test server is Linux, deployment server is, for the moment, windows xp). I am having nightmarish problems regarding getting reports for my company's web app to print uniformly across machines and have decided that it would be best to generate PDF files instead.

I've looked around for a decent converter and the most promising looking was html2pdf, but I can't seem to get it to actually function (it spits out a massive number of depreciation warnings and terminates with undefined functions regardless of what library I try to get it to use) so I don't think it's viable to my situation.

To clarify, what I really want is for my user to click on a link (or button) on my site and have it generate a PDF for download and instant viewing. Furthermore, I want it to use my current HTML5 reports and simply convert them, rather than being forced to recreate them using the native PDF libraries.

So, experts, can anyone point me in a direction that will lead to success?

Comment: If you're willing to pay the license fee, PrinceXML is worth a go - but not cheap! A demo binary for all platforms is available.

Comment: Wow... I don't think I'm going to convince my boss to fork out nearly $4000 for a pdf library. That's insane! Too bad because it seems fairly solid.

Comment: What's your use case? If it is tabulated/x-tab/chart-based reports, consider an editor & server solution such as iReport and Jasper. You'd have to redesign what you have, but with a GUI it may not be so onerous.

Comment: I thought about going that route, but we wanted this tracking system to be self-contained and not rely on external sources for anything. Basically my boss wants to be able to just go onto the site and click the button without worrying about anything else. The frustrating part of it is that on linux I can just "print to PDF" straight from Opera/Chrome and not worry about anything else but can't seem to match that functionality on the windows terminals the employees use.

Comment: In that case, discovering what technology that is based on might point to a solution (if you're happy with the output - browser to print has been historically poor). Is that a Linux-based CUPS driver or a browser technology?

Comment: I suspect that my printing issues will probably be the same trying to "print to pdf" on windows terminals as it is when I print to a regular printer. All it actually does is totally resize the page so that instead of fitting the page perfectly (like it does on linux) it prints it as maybe a half of a page in the top left corner on windows. This totally baffles me, because the CSS is set to inches and is the same on both servers.

Comment: Sure, but find out what technology is used on the Linux version, if you're happy with that PDF output. That can then be run on your Linux web server so that all users get decent PDF results.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how it's calling the print to file. It's not through CUPS because there's no pdf driver set up for it, and for that matter I can't seem to find a single pdf driver on the system. Going to have to run a stack trace to figure out what call it's actually using I guess.

Comment: That would be worth a go, although I should think docs on it would be available online if we knew what keywords to search for. If it's in both Linux-based browsers, I should think it is something at the system level. Is it available in any other software, such as Open Office?

Comment: [This](http://linuxneophyte.com/print-to-pdf-cups-pdf/) seems to point to CUPS, although it could be different I guess. Much the same [here](http://www.arsgeek.com/2007/05/17/5-steps-to-create-a-pdf-printer-print-to-pdf-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8721/discussion-between-nathan-cox-and-halfer)

Answer (score 1):

This is also worth a go:

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

I seem to remember it wouldn't work out for us as the pagination control wasn't as good as Prince - but still take a look. This one is free `:)`

Comment: I'll check out the php bindings. I'd seen this, but it seemed to have a lot of negative press around it so I didn't seriously consider it.